# p_align: How do ELF Loaders handle the possibility of two loadable segments occupying same virtual page?

Tags: elf

It's from my understanding that the 'p_align' field of program headers allows the loader to easily determine if it can just do a simple mmap of file pages to memory pages in order load a section.

However, I was thinking of the following edge case:
Suppose that the end of one loadable segment in main memory barely goes into a new page (lets call this page P). Then, another loadable segment needs to be loaded in memory, starting halfway in P.

The memory that these two segments occupy are non-overlapping, but the pages that they occupy are overlapping, so a simple mmap cannot be done.

Do loaders just need to check for this case and then manually load in contents to the pages containing multiple segments? Or is there some guarantee that can be made that segments don't share virtual pages?

I would imagine such a guarantee would greatly simplify the work of loaders, but maybe it wouldn't help that much since loaders need to anyways do checks to determine if an ELF file is valid?

As a side question, is the 'p_align' field even really needed? Couldn't the maximum alignment very quickly be determined by counting the trailing zeros in the binary representation of abs(p_vaddr - p_offset)?
Furthermore, the man pages https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html
State that

> Loadable process segments must have congruent values for p_vaddr and p_offset, modulo the page size.

So loaders don't even need to check if loadable segments can/can't be mmapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's from my understanding that the 'p_align' field of program headers allows the loader to easily determine if it can just do a simple mmap of file pages to memory pages in order load a section.

Your understanding (and the entire premise of your question) is wrong: the `LOAD` segments *always* tell the loader how to `mmap` segments into memory, and `.p_align` field has nothing to do with that.

There is no "manually load contents" of any kind in the loader(s).

Comment: Then as just a follow up, what exactly is the point of the p_align field? Every source online has only said something vague about it saying the "required alignment" of segment or only that its a value so that p_vaddr = p_offset mod p_allign. Using readelf, I can see that LOAD segments have p_align of 4KB. The modulo statement with p_align being 4KB mathematically guarantees its possible to mmap file pages to memory pages to correctly load the segment. This is the only utility I see for p_align. But it is anyways required for p_align of LOAD segments to be page-sized, so is there no purpose?

Comment: @jellojar There _is_ a reason to use `p_align` other than 4096, but it requires a longish answer. Ask a separate question about it (it's free :-).

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far; I have made a new question.